# Java Arrays,Reversing values of one array to another

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    //this program is to print the index values of an array in reversed order using 
    //another array
    int[]array1={5,6};
    int[]array2= new int[2];
    int i;
    int j=1;

    for(i=0;i<=1;i++){

        array1[i]=array2[j];
        j--;

    }
    for(int num: array1)
        System.out.println(num);

}
```

**I am not getting the output of array2 by reversing the index value of array1 and storing it in array2. Can anybody tell me the reason?**

Comment: You don't print out `array2`?!

Comment: Because in Java, assignment puts the value on the **right** side into the variable on the **left** side. See your assignment statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two mistakes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {5, 6};
    int[] array2 = new int[array1.length];
    int i;
    int j = array1.length -1;
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array2[i] = array1[j]; //  Fixed mistake
        j--;
    }
    for (int num : array2) { // fixed mistake
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code has two errors:

- You changed values of `array1` instead of `array2`
- You printed `array1`, the original array, not `array2` the reverted array.

Change your code

```
for(i=0;i<=1;i++){

    array1[i]=array2[j];
    j--;

}
for(int num: array1)
    System.out.println(num);
```

to the following code (I also added a different spacing that is more readable)

```
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    array2[i] = array1[j];
    j--;
}
// Iterate over array2
for (int num: array2) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things that you'd missed.

1. The assignment `array1[i]=array2[j];` should be the other way around.
2. The loop should iterate over `array2`. `for(int num: array1)` should be `for(int num: array2)`.

Here, I fixed it for you:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array1 = { 5, 6 };
        int[] array2 = new int[2];
        int i;
        int j = 1;

        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {

            array2[i] = array1[j];
            j--;

        }
        for (int num : array2)
            System.out.println(num);
    }
```